# Flutter: How to handle image with null value?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I try simple layout from data.
It should be just a text and image.
However, looking at the data it have "image", null or video.

My idea is when image= null, just show a transparent file.
But how to handle video?

```
List profileImage = ["picture1.jpg", null  , "picture3.jpg", "profile_video_3.mp4"];

              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Stack Oveflow'),
                  Image.asset('assets/quizImages/$FromprofileImage')
                ],
              ),
```

Expected output is layout have text widget and handle the "image widget" for null value and video file

What is the best practice to handle this?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how you can go about it.

```
List profileImage = ["picture1.jpg", null  , "picture3.jpg", "profile_video_3.mp4"];
Scaffold(
    body: Column(
        children: <Widget> [
                Text('Stack Oveflow'),
                _displayMedia(profileImage[0]),

            ]
        )
)

Widget _displayMedia(String media) {
    if(media == null) {
        return Image.asset('assets/transparent_file');
    }
    else if(media.contains('.mp4') {
        return Image.asset('assets/video_thumbnail.png');
    }
    else {
        return Image.asset('assets/quizImages/$media');
    }

}
```

For the video thumbnail image, you can check here on how to generate it. https://medium.com/@sreedevr/creating-thumbnail-from-video-in-flutter-d569000eaeac

Comment: Thanks. Seems missing ")" in one of the lines